# 80 Gallon Ingersoll Rand fell over, is it safe to use?

Tags: air-compressor

I have a new Ingersoll Rand 80 gallon tank compressor that fell over while we were unloading it off the fork lift. It’s really unfortunate but luckily it was still on the pallet so when it fell it fell flat to where the only parts damaged were the electric motor fan cover and the pump filter housing and tank. The tank took the brunt of the fall on concrete. We got it stood back up and now the tank has a light flat spot where the cylinder is welded to the end cap. It’s definitely dented now at the weld near the top of the tank. My question is is it ok to have a dent like that or should I trash the entire tank and buy a new one? I spent a bunch of money on this darn thing. We definitely underestimated the weight of this thing. Are dented air tanks safe to use? I can’t really find much information out there about dents in air tanks. Most dangers of air tanks that I can find is from rust and some of them eventually exploding.

Comment: If you call lucky about every part getting hit or damaged I hope that is sarc. Damage to a pressure vessel can lead to real hazards most of these tanks are only 150 psi or less but on a large volume there can be issues if not anchored and it splits. I was a certified inspector for scuba tanks and any deviation in those tanks would condemn the tank, as we only have your description I would say the tank is unsafe.  I have seen low pressure tanks work with some damage but flat on a welded seam ???

Comment: I know your pain.  We have an Ingersoll Rand Model 30 same thing happened to. Only this one beaned and cracked the compressor pulley, and possibly damaged the shaft/bearings. We're waiting to see.  And I agree with the idea of hydro-test it to be sure.